# Approximation of function

Tags: analysis

Let $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.\

I have to show the following:

> $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we can find some $g$ in $S$ such that $|f(x)−g(x)| < \epsilon \forall x ∈ [a,b]$.

My approach:

> $\forall \epsilon > 0$, by characterisation of infimum, there exists some $g \in \{p(x) : p ∈ S; p \geq f\}$ such that $g(x) < f(x) + \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. 
> By definition, $g \in S$.
> Also, $g \geq f$, which implies $g(x) - f(x) \geq 0 \forall x \in [a,b]$. 
> Then $|g(x) - f(x)| = g(x) - f(x)$.
> Therefore $g(x) < f(x) + \epsilon$ implies $|g(x) - f(x)| = |f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$. 
> The proof is finished.

Comment: By "$\forall p, q \in S$, min $(p(x), q(x)) \in S$ for all $x \in [a,b]$" you probably mean "$\forall p, q \in S$,  $r\in S,$ where $r(x)=\min(p(x), q(x))$ for all $x \in [a,b]$". Anyway, your proof fails from the beginning because the element $g\in S$ generally depends on $x.$

Comment: Then think of editing your post to make the correction. And do you understand why your proof fails?

Comment: But if you fix it, your $g$ will satisfy the requirement only for that $x.$ So I think your try is a dead end. And a correct proof should use the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

For $y \in [a,b]$, let $p_y\in S$ be such that $p_y\ge f$ and $p_y(y)-f(y)< \epsilon$.

By continuity of $f$ and $p_y,$ there is an open interval $S_y \subset [a,b]$ such that $y\in S_y$ and $p_y(x) - f(x)< 3\epsilon$, $\forall x \in S_y$.

Now $\cup_y S_y = [a,b]$. But since $[a,b]$ is compact, we have $\cup_{i=1}^n S_{y_i} = [a,b]$.

Now take $q =\min(p_{y_1},p_{y_2},...,p_{y_n})$. Since $p_{y_i} \geq f$ for all $i,$ we have that $q\ge f.$ This $q$ will satisfy $0\le q(x)-f(x)< 3 \epsilon$, thus solving your problem.

Comment: (+1) For $y=a$ or $b,$ there is no "open interval $S_y\subset[a,b]$ such that $y\in S_y$" (this is just a matter of style and can be easily repaired, at the cost of some heavyness).